Water Shutoff during vacation
Water Shutoff
Please advise. I am going on a 2 week vacation and planning to turn off the water supply and gas water heater to pilot mode.
Could someone please tell me if I need to do anything other than turning off the lever? Should I be opening any taps after I turn off the water?
Also when am back, what's the best way to turn on the water supply and also the water heater to on mode?
Thanks so much!

You're overthinking (and thus overcomplicating)  it.
If you have a ball-type (1/4 turn lever) main shutoff, just shut it off, turn the water heater to pilot, leave.
When you return, turn it on, turn the water heater to on.
If (instead, but you say "lever" so likely a ball valve) you have a gate valve main, you need to be very cautious about the force with which you open and close it, as they have a nasty habit of breaking, at which point you need to have the water turned off from outside and replace it with a 1/4 turn ball valve main shutoff.
"But what if my pipes burst?" There isn't much water in the pipes, so any leakage would be very limited. The only thing with a lot of water in it is your water heater, and draining that requires turning it off, and is a chore, and the inconvenience of re-lighting the pilot after refilling it when you get home. If the water heater is located in the attic, you could conceivably end up with that much leakage, at most. In the basement, the only way the water would come out of it would be via a leak lower than it. In any case, even that much water is much less than what happens if the main shutoff is open when you have a leak.
Draining the pipes is a needless level of fuss for an unlikely event.
Turning off and draining the water heater is an absurd level of fuss for an unlikely event.
99% of the "vacation leak disasters" (and "while you were away at work" disasters) would be addressed by simply having (and using) a quick shutoff (1/4 turn hot and cold valve in one) on the clothes washer connection before the rubber hoses, that you only turn on when actually washing clothes, and turn off when done, every time. Unless your house freezes while you are on vacation, pipes don't randomly burst much. Washing machine hoses occasionally do.

Thank you very much! When I turn the water back on, I read somewhere that I need to slowly turn it on (and not fully) and wait for the water to fill up the pipes. Once the water fills up the pipes, turn it on fully. I have a ball type lever. Also then go to the top most floor and open each tap? That's the process am not sure about? Should I keep the taps open or closed when I turn the water back on.

forgot to tag you @Ecnerwal

If you don't drain the pipes, they are already full of water. Only if you drain them so they are full of air do you need to purge the air out of them. Thus, less fuss to leave them full of water, and just turn the valve back on.
